# Process to put wamp server online

Tags: windows, networking, web, hosting

Can anyone guide me, how to put wamp server online. Please tell me the whole process that i need to do to put it online. I want to host my own website.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wamp server is a Windows Web development environment for Apache, MySQL, PHP databases.it's a Web development platform on Windows that allows you to test dynamic Web applications LOCALLY.

You can't host you website with this.

You need a web host like OVH.

However, you can register a free DDNS ( like no-ip) ,implement it with your internet box, and configure WAMP with this.

And you will be able to host your website with your own computer

you can find a tutorial here : http://www.noip.com/support/.../diy-hosting-using-no-ip-wamp/

Answer (score 0):

Windows: How to Host a Website Using Your PC as a WAMP Server

First, let’s try hosting a website using your personal computer with the Windows operating system.

Step 1: Install the WAMP Software

To make this super easy, we’ll use a WAMP installation program (of which there are several) called WampServer. You could also opt to install each package manually, but this process requires much more work and is error-prone.

The WampServer package is delivered with the latest releases of Apache, MySQL, and PHP.

WampServer is one of several environments available to create Apache, MySQL, and PHP applications on Windows.

First, download the 32-bit or 64-bit WAMP-binary here, and begin the installation. Just follow the on-screen instructions, and when it’s done, launch WampServer.

Note: There may be a port 80 conflict with your Skype software, but there’s a fix for that.

Step 2: Using WampServer

Upon installation, a www directory will be created automatically. You’ll likely find it here: c:\wamp\www

From that directory, you can create subdirectories (called “projects” in WampServer), and put any HTML or PHP files inside those subdirectories.

The main screen of your localhost in WampServer should look something like this.

If you click on the localhost link in the WampSever menu or open your internet browser with the URL http://localhost, you should be shown the main screen of WampServer.

Step 3: Creating an HTML Page

To test our WampServer, we can put an example file called “info.php” into our www-directory.

Go directly to this directory by clicking “www directory” in the WampServer menu.

From there, create a new file with the contents below, and save it.

1

PHP Test

Now you can browse to http://localhost/info.php to see the details of your PHP installation. You can create any HTML and PHP file structure to suit your needs.

Step 4: Configure MySQL

If you click on the phpMyAdmin menu option, you can start configuring your MySQL databases (which may be needed for a CMS like WordPress).

The phpMyAdmin login screen will open in a new browser window. By default, the admin username will be root, and you can leave the password field blank.

From there, you can create new MySQL databases and alter existing ones. Most software, like WordPress, will automatically set up a new database for you, though.

Step 5: Make the Site Public

By default, the Apache configuration file is set to deny any incoming HTTP connections, except in the case of someone coming from the localhost.

To make your site publicly accessible, you need to change the Apache configuration file (httpd.conf). You can find and edit this file by going to the WampServer menu, clicking “Apache,” and selecting “httpd.conf.”

1

2

Order Deny,Allow

Deny from all

Replace the two lines above with the ones below:

1

2

Order Allow,Deny

Allow from all

Restart all WampServer services by clicking “Restart all Services” in the menu.

The site should now be accessible from beyond your localhost. Confirm there isn’t a PC firewall blocking web requests. You may need to set up port-forwarding on your internet router as well.

Step 6: Using a Domain Name

To use a domain name, such as Example Domain, with your WAMP installation, we’ll need to configure some files first. Let’s assume our Example Domain domain has an A record in your DNS with the IP address 100.100.100.100.

First, we need to add the following line to the C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file:

1

100.100.100.100 Example Domain

Now, we need to edit httpd.conf again (accessible via the WampServer menu) to add a virtual host. Once that file is open, look for “Virtual hosts,” and uncomment the line after it, like this:

1

2

## Virtual hosts

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Now we need to add a file manually in “C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache-VERSION\conf\extra\” (VERSION is your Apache version).

Then create a file in Notepad with the following content, and save it in that Apache directory.

1

2

3

4

5

ServerAdmin mail@example.com

DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www"

ServerName mysite.local

ErrorLog "logs/example.com.log"

CustomLog "logs/example.com-access.log" common

Click “Restart All Services” in the WampServer menu to activate these changes.

Now your site should also be accessible via its domain name.

Linux: How to Host A Website on a Linux Machine

Let’s now cover how to set up Apache, MySQL, and PHP on a Linux system.

Step 1: Install Software

To start our LAMP software install, type the following in the terminal:

1

sudo apt install apache2 mysql-server php libapache2-mod-php7.0

During the installation process, you will be asked to enter (and re-enter) a password for the MySQL root user.

Have your MySQL root password handy during the LAMP installation process.

Technically, it’s not necessary (as it should have been done upon installation), but just to be sure, we will restart the Apache web server.

Any time you change the global configuration of Apache, you need to execute the command below, unless you do the configuration using local .htaccess files.

1

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Step 2: Check PHP

To confirm your PHP server works and see what PHP modules are currently available, you can place a test PHP file in the web server root directory (/var/www/html/):

1

sudo echo "" > /var/www/html/info.php

We can now visit that PHP page by browsing to http://localhost/info.php.

You should see the currently running PHP version, current configuration, and currently installed modules. Note that you can later install other PHP modules using the Ubuntu package manager, as some PHP applications might require that.

To determine which extra modules are available, search within the graphical package manager, or simply use the command line:

1

apt search php | grep module

Step 3: Check MySQL

As most CMS systems (e.g., WordPress) use MySQL, we will also look at that part.

To see if your MySQL installation is working, type “service mysql status.”

1

2

3

4

5

$ service mysql status

● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server

[...]

mrt 15 13:24:09 host1 systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.

We see that MySQL is up and running. If you don’t see this, you can type “sudo service mysql restart” to restart the MySQL server.

From here, we can use the MySQL command line client to manage databases.

For this, we need to use the admin credentials we typed earlier when MySQL was installed.

1

2

3

$ mysql -u root -p

[now you will be asked for our admin password and enter the mysql prompt]

From here, we can do anything we want with MySQL, e.g., create a new database:

1

2

CREATE DATABASE test;

USE test;

Often times, the CMS will automatically create the database for you, but sometimes you need to do something to the database manually (e.g., create a backup or optimize tables).

PHPMyAdmin is a friendly database management tool most web experts will recommend.

You can install PHPmyadmin by typing the following into the terminal: